Is philosophy stack exchange Philosophy 101, or is it a place for ideas?
There is a place for signposting philosophy students or amateur philosophers, but is it acceptable to develop ideas through Q&A without being closed for "opinion"? Is it possible that answers could be kept brief with relevant references? Could we stop with the comments already? An answer is worth a shedload of comments. Is this a place for philosophers or just students and pedants? I prefer to allow debate and keep my answers succinct. Am I getting this all wrong?

This site is not meant to "develop ideas" or for debate. The entire StackExchange format is for clear, singular questions, with responses in the form of answers.
Even where certain topics might be better suited for a discussion forum rather than StackExchange's Q&A, the choice to use this Q&A platform is a choice to accept its norms.
I agree most comments on this site are an inappropriate use of comments:

Comments almost always immediately stray into stating an aphorism, asking a different question, or providing a partial answer.

This is not a proper use of comments.
If someone suggests an edit to a post in a comment, and the edit is not made, it can be inferred that the post author has disagreed. There is no need to reply if it is as simple as you not agreeing. You can even flag the comment as having been read and you deciding not to respond. The comment author can downvote to signal disagreement and write their own competing answer if they would like to preserve their view.

@DikranMarsupial I am stuck in a pile of work atm but starting a meta thread asking whether the community wants a change to "Improve this post" on the comment button (next step: feature-request tag) is on the list.

On the answer itself: Nothing to add. As I have written on meta time and again: This site is part of the StackExchange network first and on the subject of philosophy second.

@DikranMarsupial Do list out the 5(?) top reasons for your decision. I've seen ppl use a meta post for this on multiple occasions.

This is a more specific answer regarding your contributions.
While I agree with you that I would prefer a freer discussion on a wider, less regimented set of topics, your own questions and answers are too thin even for me. You need to put more of yourself into your questions rather than be like a tennis player who serves by gently lobbing the ball that asks fro a long volley of discussion.
IOW I like Q/A to be more open ended than currently, but not so open ended that there is no discernible direction!

I have noticed a tendency for people to get irritated with more difficult questions that don't have ready cookie-cutter answers.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance which is near the same as saying ppl get irritated with philosophical questions. The cookie cutter q/as are something else: "Did Spinoza say...?" History. "What does Deleuze mean when he says..." Historiography. Or more specialized areas — religion, linguistics, physics...

Phil-SE represents a full head-on clash between SE on the one hand which is good for superuser, ubuntu, stackoverflow (original) etc, ie the technical sites where demarcation is not a question and with philosophy on the other hand which starts with questions, proceeds through discussion and ideally ends with clearer better questions.
Unfortunately what goes on here is by default closer to philosophology than philosophy.
Also the VTC (vote-to-close) is among the most overused and misused features because people have figured out it can be used as a costless downvote.
This (among a dozen other reasons) is why I almost never cast VTC, even though Ive seen hundreds of questions I would have closed in a more functional system.
This is the more generic answer regarding the site.

I feel this is polemic as it paints a picture so easy it's incorrect. Look at one of the most rigorously moderated sites of the network (skeptics): it's not necessarily about history or whatever but about having to collect and critically discuss assertions and claims on the basis of publicly available sources. Yes, this requires a lot of knowledge or work but SE is about "Experts answering your questions", not about "some random guy offering their unsolicited opinion and advice to what they think your problem may be". If this was taken seriously the userbase would be different.

Also, we have perfectly valid questions asking about philosophy courses, essay marking, resource databases, and others. In a sense, MO is not that different from how Philosophy.SE should work like. I've not seen complaints about this site being primarily about "history of maths".

+1 for 'philosophology' and Robert Pirsig, the "Uncle Bob" of Philosophy.

I agree with you @DikranMarsupial. Skeptics is not moderated; its policed. And from an absurdly narrow slant. I've never been there because it's a joke. But I was on politics-SE. I soon realized US:good guy; Russia:bad guy is to be axiomatically assumed. And when the cheerleaders for genocide far outnumbered the humans I deleted.

@PhilipKlöcking By contrast  this site is way better. I can say here : Too much western Christian bias out here Now imagine me telling  skeptics I am alive because of homeopathy

@PhilipKlöcking I don't know what you find "polenic" but I suspect this answer expands
